# Document Database for Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, mongodb, couchdb, document

I am developing an Android application that must sync data with a database that exposes data over REST API calls. It needs to periodically download changed data and store them locally so they are available offline.

The catch is that the remote database is a document database and so I'm not just getting back flat tables, I am getting back documents with nested children and nested arrays.

I can't just translate this into SQLite for querying using with adapters. I need to either

1. Store the data in files on the device (cannot query, or use with BaseAdapter easily)
2. Translate the data from document-oriented to relational on the device (lots of error-prone code)
3. Use an embedded document database

I would like option 3, but I can't seem to find a realistic usable solution for this. Are there any options I'm not seeing or does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Couchbase-Lite-Android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) to see if it works for you as a mobile, syncable NoSQL data store. I haven't used it though.

If that doesn't work for you, then consider the Java driver for MongoDB. It has had [Android support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-295) for quite a while now, and `BasicDBObject` should provide the level of abstraction you need. It would make mapping to SQLite a little less painful.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying to connect directly to the remote mongo database? Even if I did that I would still have the same problem though, I need to cache the data locally for offline use. I have to translate to relational data?

Comment: My bad. I was in a hurry before and misread your question. Check out my edit.